# Problems connecting tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to connect my url with the tortoise program, but when I connect it, I get this error, does anyone know why?[image]

Comment: **Path not found** is pretty self-explanatory. Are you positively sure that a service hosted in a subdomain with **git** on its name actually contains an **svn** repository?

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want to use [SourceForge's Git](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Git/) with a Subversion tool. That combination can't work because Git and Subversion are completely different version control systems. Your alternatives:

- Use [SourceForge's Subversion](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/svn/)
- Use [tools designed for Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

If unsure, stick to Git.